# Proof of matroids

Tags: optimization, matroids

We have set $S$ and subset $I = 2^S \setminus \{S\}$. Show that $M=(S,I)$ is a matroid.
Is it graphic, linear or a matching matroid?

I am little struggling how to prove this, there should be 3 things to prove.

- $\varnothing\in I$
- if $i \in I$ and $j \subseteq i$, then $j \in I$
- if $i,j \in I$ and $|i|<|j|$, then $i+x \in I$ for some $x \in j\setminus i$

Any ideas how to prove that, the $2^S$ is kinda making me confused in the prove.

Comment: The $2^S$ is just a fancy way to say that $I$ is the matroid of all proper subsets of $S$.  To show that a set belongs to $I$, just show that it is a subset of $S$ (but not all of $S$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$2^S$ is the power set of $S$, i.e., the collection of all subsets of $S$. We’re throwing away $S$ itself, the biggest of these subsets, so $I$ is the collection of all *proper* subsets of $S$. You could write $$I=\{i\subseteq S:i\ne S\}\;.$$

> If, for example, $S=\{0,1,2\}$, then $I=\big\{\varnothing,\{0\},\{1\},\{2\},\{0,1\},\{0,2\},\{1,2\}\big\}$: it contains $7$ of the $2^3=8$ subsets of $S$ $-$ all of them except $S=\{0,1,2\}$ itself.

It’s automatic, therefore, that $\varnothing\in I$ (provided that $S$ is non-empty, which I’m sure you’re intended to assume). The hereditary property, which I’ll leave to you, is also automatic. The augmentation property isn’t much harder. Suppose that $i,j\in I$ with $|i|<|j|$. Then there is certainly some $x\in j\setminus i$; let $i'=i\cup\{x\}$. To show that $i'\in I$, you need to show that $i'\ne S$. But $|i'|=|i|+1\le|j|$ (why?), so ... ?

Some hints for the second part of the question:

1. Consider the [cycle graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_graph) on $|S|$ vertices. It has $|S|$ edges; what’s the only set of edges that is not a forest?
2. Let $n=|S|-1$. For $k=1,\dots,n$ let $e_k$ be the unit vector in $\Bbb R^n$ that has a $1$ in the $k$-th componenet and $0$ everywhere else, and let $e_0=\langle\underbrace{1,1,\dots,1}_n\rangle$. Let $S=\{s_0,s_1,\dots,s_n\}$, and define $h:S\to\Bbb R^n:s_k\mapsto e_k$. What subsets of $\{e_0,e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ are linearly independent?
3. The rank of a matching matroid is always even. The cycle graphs are useful here, too; consider $C_n$ for even and odd $n$ separately.

Comment: From what I understood this matroid is graphic because the set I that induces is forest and the only set of edges not being forest is S itself.

Comment: From what I understood this matroid is graphic because the set I that induces is forest and the only set of edges not being forest is S itself.

An if you are saying that rank of matching matroid is always even, then the rank of the matrix {{1,1,0},{1,0,1},{0,1,1}} is odd. Yet when use S={0,1,2,3} the rank is 2 so even. So it is not matching matroid? Not sure if I am doing this right.